# Error while trying to copy file to many files using cp

Tags: command-line, cp

Error when running this command, I think the command is clear to get the idea.

`cp file.txt /folder/*/*/*/file.txt`

I found out cp dosen't support *, so how can I do the same thing in bash or command-line

Comment: The wildcards are handled by the shell already. If `cp` is complaining at you it's because your wildcarded path is matching more than one file (and the last match is not a directory).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? FYI, `cp` copies SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY. Your command doesn't seem to have a DIRECTORY at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in /folder/*/*/*
do
   [ -d "$i" ] && cp file.txt "$i"
done
```